# Broken bookdown heading link with duplicate names

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

I am preparing some documentation in bookdown (gitbook) with a heading structure like the following:

```
1. Subject A
    1.1. Properties
2. Subject B
    2.1. Properties
```

When I click on the 2.1 link I am directed to section 1.1.

Is it possible to have two headings with the same name and have the links work correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that two chapters with the same name are automatically equipped with the same ID. To get different links, you have to assign different IDs to Chapters 1.1. and 2.1 manually by adding `{#ID}` behind the titles. For example:

```
# Subject1

text

## Properties {#properties-1}

text

# Subject2

text

## Properties {#properties-2}

text
```

The ID in `{#ID}` can then also be used to link to a specific chapter like `[this](#ID)`.

Comment: The original problem should be gone if you update **bookdown** from CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/package=bookdown (current version is v0.21)