# Links not generated correctly in bookdown menu

Tags: r, bookdown

If I have the same subsection titles in different chapters (the problem onlæy occurs if have a Rmd file for each chapter), then following the link in the menu goes to the first subsection.

I have tried to make a small reprex at https://github.com/relund/bookdown-reprex. The error only occurs when you have multiple files.

1. [Extract the zip](https://github.com/relund/bookdown-reprex/archive/master.zip)
2. Knit index.Rmd
3. In the resulting output (index.html), clicking on the link for 'Learning outcomes' in the menu under Chapter 3 links to 'Learning outcomes' in Chapter 2 and not as it should to Chapter 3

```
xfun::session_info('bookdown')
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134), RStudio 1.3.959

Locale:
  LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
  LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

Package version:
  base64enc_0.1.3 bookdown_0.20   digest_0.6.25   evaluate_0.14   glue_1.4.2      graphics_3.6.3  grDevices_3.6.3 highr_0.8       htmltools_0.5.0
  jsonlite_1.7.1  knitr_1.29      magrittr_1.5    markdown_1.1    methods_3.6.3   mime_0.9        rlang_0.4.7     rmarkdown_2.3   stats_3.6.3    
  stringi_1.4.6   stringr_1.4.0   tinytex_0.25    tools_3.6.3     utils_3.6.3     xfun_0.16       yaml_2.2.1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Broken bookdown heading link with duplicate names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63898924/broken-bookdown-heading-link-with-duplicate-names)

Comment: Partly. The hack is useful but cumbersome if you have many subsections with the same name. Moreover, as I point out it in fact works if you specify subsections in a single file. Anyway I will use it until the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in **bookdown** v0.21 (which was just released to CRAN). You can update or reinstall **bookdown** from CRAN:

```r
install.packages('bookdown')
# or
update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
```